# Can't make post with axios to Laravel App

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

i tried many times to post an ajax request with axios using vuejs to lararvel app
i added the csrf_token() in meta master blade.
but the status always returns as 419 (Unknown Status),
If some has got similar type of error then please help.

Comment: Show Some code to help you

Answer (score 2):

You must assign value of `csrf_token()` to some field in your layout file. I would suggest you use like this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If you are using Laravel mix to compile your JS & CSS, then the csrf_token is automatically added to the axios configuration. Following is the code in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` for axios configuration whenever you create a Laravel application.

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
}
```

For above to work automatically, you need to run `npm install` or `yarn install` if you have installed yarn.

Comment: Thanks i already do this i'm using laravel-mix in (Laravel 5.5)